# Stuck on boot "Faild to start network interface"

Tags: boot, network-manager, broadcom, atheros, raspberrypi

This is my error:

[image: Network_failure]

and this is the output of `systemctl status networking.service`:

[image: systemctl_status]

The output of `journalctl -xb` does not provide any information on the problem.

The weird thing is, it has something to do with mac-changer but I didn't install any mac-changer and I cant delete it from the system, it seems it's protected and was "built-in" the kernel..

So I'm stuck on the boot menu, `systemctl reboot` or `systemctl default` will not boot up my system, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed any macchanger, you can remove `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger` and then restart your network manager:

**Edit**

If your root filesystem is Read-only, first mount it in **read-write** mode:
`sudo mount / -o remount,rw`

Then:
`sudo rm /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger -f
 sudo systemctl restart network`

Comment: Cant remove it since its a "Read-only file system" even with sudo or -f option.

Comment: if your root filesystem is Read-only, you can remount it in 'read-write' mode (`sudo mount / -o remount,rw`) and then delete macchanger.

Comment: Could you write the full command to run on terminal? the file is at /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/macchanger